# jQuery Ajax post with both file and data??

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

These lines below are the form data that I need to post using an AJAX request, and get back a JSON response.

```
<textarea type='text' id="newStatusBox">Your Status here...</textarea>
Link:<input type="text" id="newStatusLink"/>
Video:<input type="text" id="newStatusVideo"/>
Image : <input type="file" id="newStatusImage" size="20" />
<input type='button' value="post" id="status-post-button" onclick='postStatus()'/>
```

When I use the $.ajax of jQuery in postStatus() to post the data, I'm not getting the image file in that page.

Is there any other solution to achieve what I want?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot upload files via AJAX unless people use a recent browser.

Anyway, you can simply use the [jQuery form plugin](http://jquery.malsup.com/form/). If you have a file upload field in your form it will fallback to a hidden IFRAME instead of XHR. However, in this case your response must be sent as `text/html` and wrapped in a `<textarea>` since it cannot send a proper JSON content type as it would cause browsers to show a download dialog.

You could also have a look at http://www.plupload.com/ which wraps tons of upload technologies and uses the best one available for each user.

Comment: Why did you downvote @amolv's answer that included info about uploadify jQuery plugin. Granted it uses Flash for it, but OP never said they want a pure Javascript solution. It still is jQuery plugin and it could be used in this scenario just as well. Plupload that you also suggested may just as well use Flash... Not necessarily but it can.

Comment: Plupload *can* use flash. Uploadify *only* uses flash.